# Is it possible to know what route is used in HandleFunc

Tags: go

I am using `http.HandleFunc("/resource", resource.Handle)` from the package `net/http` and I was wondering if there was a way to see what route (in this case `/resource`) is used to get you to `resource.Handle`? Or do I have to create a `Mux` for this?

I'd like to know this to extract the resource from the url path to do some magic with it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can

The main points to do:

- Use the `DefaultServeMux` used by the `HandleFunc` method.
- Construct a fake `http.Request`

For Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {

    theUrl, err := url.Parse("/response")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/response", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    })

    handler, path := http.DefaultServeMux.Handler(&http.Request{Method: "GET", URL: theUrl})

    fmt.Println(handler, path)

}
```

see this [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/IUG9h7_3yk)

Comment: This works like a charm. One note tho, /response handles just that, /response/ handles /response/.*, but this was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request

Use `request.URL.Path` to get the path used to access the handler.

Comment: This returns the current complete url path. What I'm looking for is just the route. I would like to get /resource (the resource name) in the case of  /resource/foo

Comment: @MartijnvanMaasakkers HandleFunc doesn't have a concept of resources and routes. It just handles paths, so that's what you get. Other frameworks wrap it or replace it and give you the semantic concepts. You can either write your own path parser and routing utils, or you can use one of these.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer is correct there. Use something like gorilla/mux or a lightweight framework for its router: many provide a r.Params["resource"] map for you to inspect using named routes.